# How to add VM arguments to ECS container definition in Terraform?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, terraform, amazon-ecs

I have this application that depends on two types of profiles, when I pass a VM arguments as "-Dspring.profiles.active="test"", it loads some specific beans, and when I load the application with "-Dspring.profiles.active="test2", it loads the application with other beans. I'm loading a docker with this application's image inside an ECS using terraform. Here's the container definition:

```
  {
    "essential": true,
    "image": "docker-image",
    "name": "app",
    "environment": [
      {
        "name": "spring.profiles.active",
        "value": "test1"
      },
     ]"
}
```

I've tried passing the spring profile inside the environent value, but without any success. Is there something I can do? Thanks!

Comment: You can probably use `entryPoint` and/or `command` but I guess some details are lacking in your question.

Comment: According to the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html what you have should work just fine.  You can also try using `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` as the environment variable name, instead of `spring.profiles.active` as mentioned in the documentation I linked.

Comment: Please note that if you are also setting VM arguments, using `-Dspring.profiles.active="test"` via the `CMD` or `ENDPOINT` settings, then that is going to override the environment variable you are trying to set. Your question asks about setting VM arguments, but the code you show is setting environment variables.

Comment: Setting CMD or ENDPOINT is just a testing. I tried using those two that you mentioned (spring.profiles.active and SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE). Both did not work :(